# Can I set ntlm authentication for a mail server via the web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, email, authentication

Is it possible to specify that you want to use NTLM authentication for SMTP using system.net, all via the web.config file? If so, what needs to be done?

I've been told adding the following will cause NTLM or Kerberos to be used if the SMTP server requires it, but our SMTP server is not authenticating. (I'm no SMTP expert).

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="yourhost.com" userName="user@yourhost.com" password="yourpassword" port="yourport" defaultCredentials="true" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

E.g. Should there be authentication modules specified?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2008/04/16/hacking-system-net-mail-smtpclient.aspx)